# VB 2010 - Reading xls, displaying, editing and saving. Using DataGridView

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel, datagridview

I have set up a DataGridView in vb in order to display a list of product IDs and descriptions.

Each time I load this form the dgv is empty. I can add to it by either inputting directly into cells, or using textboxes and butotns I set up.

Now I can save this as an .xls file, but I am pretty stumped when it comes to reading it back into the program when that page opens to being with.

Should I be better just using xml files or? Im confused again, AAHH! :)

Cheers, Robbie.

Answer (score 0):

You could use either.  Is the file your exporting to intended to edited?  If it's just to hold values why not just use a text file/xml.  You could store as a simple char delimited string and once you read it back in just .split it.  A simple loop will fill the grid from the array you split into.

Comment: They are meant to be edited in a product database management page,yes.
It is intended to hold products and their product IDs so they can be referenced in the program later on as well.